# Does it make sense to use the same methodology in android programming as in java programing?

Tags: java, android, service, interface, abstract-class

I want to do an android application, that has sensors, sensors can be hardware sensors or software sensors those sensors are sometimes available in the device like for example the accelerometer and sometimes i have to do those myself.

Usually when i have something that monitors something (sensor), i have a service that runs on the background.

I want to make something that allows the creation and the addition of new sensors easilly and modular. Can i do an interface that defines certain methods that all sensors must have and then create an abstract class that extends service and implements the interface i defined earlier? Like this:

```
public interface Sensors{

    public abstract Object getSensorData();
}

public abstract class SensorType extends Service implements Sensors{

    public abstract Object getSensorData(){
        //implementation
    }
}
```

My questions is: If i maintain a application strutural type like in java applications will that have an impact on the way the android application will behave taking in consideration that almoust every smartphone is different? For example, low performance, crashes, etc....

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? Go figure it out and ask questions when arising.

Comment: Well it probably does, but is it the best way to do it in android?

Comment: Why do you want your service implementation to be abstract? If Service is an Android Service (android.app.Service) this will not work (or requires some dirty work arounds) as the service is another Context than whatever is trying to call the `getSensorData()`. You may want to use an [AIDL](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) interface in that case and let all your Services allow to bind on that.

Comment: Because then i will have Sensor Classes that will extend this abstract  class

Comment: Service is a component of android and you need to define it in Androidmenifest.xml and service has its lifecycle you need to manage it.
Rather then creating service an abstract class, you should create a simple class for sensor, in service use collection of sensors and use AIDL to modify/interact with sensors or what ever you want to do with your custom sensor.

Comment: I would like to ask the users, Wooble, Andrew, @laalto, Arion and hexacyanide to recheck this questions and see whether the newly provided information makes the question clearer. ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Android allows you to register your services to the [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html), and get notified on values changes.

Remember that a continuous service can drain the phone battery and many devices doesn't allow you access to the sensor data when the display is turned off.